# How to hide or disable the download notification in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, notifications

I am using selenium python for the automation in Edge browser. When I perform a button action , the browser will download the files and the following notification is displayed. I don't want this notification to be displayed. How do I disable that.
Here is my code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0ClA.png)

I have tried the below

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
options.add_experimental_option( "prefs",{"profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads": 1,"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2})
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver=webdriver.Edge(options = options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set download directory path in options

```
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "<directory_path>;
#example: prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "C:\Downloads"};
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs);
```